# Is the distance between those compact sets equal to $0$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space such that there exists a sequence of compact sets of $S$  such that $K_1 \subset K_2 \subset ... $

Let $M=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} K_i$. Let $D$ be a countable dense set of $M$ ($M$ is separable).

Define $\mathcal{A} = \{ B(d,q) : q \in \mathbb Q^+_0 , d \in D\}$, where $B(d,q)$ is the open ball of center $d$ and radius $q$. This set is countable.

Define $\mathcal C = \{\emptyset\} \cup \{\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} (\bar A_i \cap K_i) : A_i \in \mathcal{A}, n \ge 1\}$

$\mathcal C$ is countable and its elements are compact sets. It is also included in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $S$.

Is it true that if we take two non-empty compact sets $C_1,C_2 \in \mathcal C$ such that $C_1 \cap C_2 = \emptyset$, we could have $d(C_1,C_2) = 0 $ ?

Comment: "The" dense set of $\;M\;$ , or "some" dense set in $\;M\;$ ? Besides this, you then use $\;\Bbb Q_0^+\;$ , and for me these are the non-negative rationals, so it seems to be you meant something inside the rationals...or inside the reals. Would you mind to explain?

Comment: $\mathcal{A}$ is not countable if $D$ is not countable. Is that a conclusion or an assumption?

Comment: @chak How do you have the slightest idea what $\;D\;$ is?? Am I missing something or the poster didn't even define that?

Comment: @DonAntonio, you're right, i should have wrote "also".

Comment: M is separable, so we take some dense countable set $D$

Comment: @W.Volante You haven't yet said where is all that happening...

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't understand your question. $D$ exists because $M$ is compact and we are in a metric space. So $M$ is separable.

Comment: @W.Volante You haven't even defined where the metric space *is*, yet you have **already** used $\;\Bbb Q_0^+\;$ ...that looks like an ill-posed question. You also talk of **the* dense set...which seems to point towards the possibility that you're talking of a very particular case...

Comment: @DonAntonio We are in a general metric space. I edited "the dense set" by "a dense set", my mistake. But for the rational radius that we are using, we do not have to precise anything on the metric space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible for any two compact sets, regardless of whether they are coming out of your question or otherwise.

The function $d:C_1\times C_2\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function on the compact space $C_1\times C_2$, so must reach a minimum. Thus, $d(C_ 1,C_2)=d(c_1,c_ 2)$ for some $c_1\in C_1, c_2\in C_2$. If $d(C_1,C_2)=0$, then $d(c_1,c_2)=0$, so $c_1=c_2\in C_1\cap C_2$, which is impossible if $C_1\cap C_2=\emptyset$.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the opposite of what I wanted, I am wondering if for those compact sets, we have $d(C_1,C_2) = 0$

Comment: My answer is still good for you. I just needed to change the first sentence from "this is true" into "this is impossible".

Comment: Of course ! :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. Suppose we did, in which case for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $x_n\in C_1$ and $y_n\in C_2$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)<\frac{1}{n}$. By compactnes let $x\in C_1$ be the limit of a converging subsequence $(x_{n_m})_m$ of $(x_n)_n$. By compactness let $y\in C_2$ be the limit of a convergent subsequence of $(y_{n_m})_m$. Since $d:S\times S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function it is easy to derive that $d(x, y)=0$.